# placement of buttons so they don't get pushed down on page

Tags: html, css

Please run each code snippet separately and notice how the buttons get pushed down below the unordered list of items.  The only difference between these code snippets are the number of list items.  If there are many items, the buttons end up way down on the page.  Is there a way to make the buttons show up under the "path contents:" label, regardless of how many list items appear?

```css
ul
{
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 padding-left: 0px;
}

button
{
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

label
{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>  
  <label id="pathcontentsLbl">path contents:</label>
  <span id="PathContents">
          <ul>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
          </ul>
        </span>
</div>

 <button id="Run">Run</button>
 <button id="Clear">Clear</button>
```

```css
ul
{
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 padding-left: 0px;
}

button
{
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

label
{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>  
  <label id="pathcontentsLbl">path contents:</label>
  <span id="PathContents">
          <ul>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
            <li>item 3</li>
            <li>item 4</li>
            <li>item 5</li>
            <li>item 6</li>
            <li>item 7</li>
            <li>item 8</li>
            <li>item 9</li>
          </ul>
        </span>
</div>

 <button id="Run">Run</button>
 <button id="Clear">Clear</button>
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the buttons to appear under the path contents label, to the left of the unordered list items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is what I found works for this problem.  The trick was using an outer container (class="container") and an inner container (class="buttons") and using the 'position' property along with the 'top' property in the CSS.

```css
ul
{
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 padding-left: 0px;
}

button
{
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

label
{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 150px;
}

.container
{
  position: relative;
}

.buttons
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">  
  <label id="pathcontentsLbl">path contents:</label>
  <span id="PathContents">
          <ul>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
            <li>item 3</li>
            <li>item 4</li>
            <li>item 5</li>
            <li>item 6</li>
            <li>item 7</li>
            <li>item 8</li>
            <li>item 9</li>
          </ul>
        </span>
  <div class="buttons">
     <button id="Run">Run</button>
   <button id="Clear">Clear</button>
  </div><!--end buttons-->
</div><!--end container-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css position property set to fixed to do it.

```
.myclass{
   position: fixed;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Hope it help you!

Answer (score 0):

Just move the buttons to the top right?

```
<div>
  <label id="pathcontentsLbl">path contents:</label>

  <button id="Run">Run</button>
  <button id="Clear">Clear</button>
  <span id="PathContents">
          <ul>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
            <li>item 3</li>
            <li>item 4</li>
            <li>item 5</li>
            <li>item 6</li>
            <li>item 7</li>
            <li>item 8</li>
            <li>item 9</li>
          </ul>
        </span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#pathcontentsLbl{
  display:block
}
```